# Explanation of the details of an accelerometer data sheet

Tags: accelerometer, precision, noise

i'm working on samsung galaxy accelerometer SMB380.
This is the data sheet: http://www.bosch-sensortec.com/content/language1/downloads/SMB380_Flyer_Rev1.3.pdf

Can someone explain me technical data on the right?
I'm especially interested in the noise and precision data.
Thx

Comment: Belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I didn't know before that it exist! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noise is 0.5 mg/Hz^-1, which tells you how much noise there will be for a given measurement bandwidth, e.g. if you filter your signal with a 100 Hz low pass filter you can expect 5 mg of noise.

As for sensitivity, there are 3 programmable ranges. The most sensitive range is 2 g. The output is 10 bits (signed, presumably) so you get 4 mg per bit, i.e. the smallest signal you can detect at a level of +/- 1 bit is 4 mg.

Comment: But how i can find the filter band in the samsung galaxy s? and wich is the range that they use? +-2g +-4g or +-8g ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the butterworth filter in matlab, the result will be perfect especially if you use this parametrer [B,A]=butter(2, 0.05)